# File's method renameTo() returns true but does not actually rename the file if I change filename's lower/upper cases

Tags: android, file, file-rename

For example:

```
String oldName = "SubFolder1";
String newName = "subfolder1";

File oldFolder = new File(getExternalFilesDir("some_folder").toString() + File.separator + oldName);
File newFolder = new File(getExternalFilesDir("some_folder").toString() + File.separator + newName);

boolean isSuccesfullyRenamed = oldFolder.renameTo(newFolder);
Log.v("rename success", isSuccessfullyRenamed);
```

Sorry if the code does not compile, but in general this returns TRUE for successful rename but the folder is not "actually" renamed from "SubFolder1" to "subfolder1".

Why does it return success? And how do I actually change the the letter casing of a folder/file that already exists on Android?

The only solution I can come up with is to create a temporary parent folder, move the file/subfolder to that temp folder, then move it back to old parent folder.

Comment: Have you granted permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE on AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Yes. I can rename just fine for other filenames as long as the file/folder does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

```
linux system equalIgnoreCase file or folder name so both 
name are same so that return true and try this below code:
private void renameFile()
{
    String oldName = "SubFolder1";
    String newName = "subfolder2";
    String root= 
    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+
    "/"+"some_folder";
    File oldFolder = new File(root,File.separator+oldName);
    File newFolder = new File(root,File.separator+newName);
    boolean isSuccesfullyRenamed = 
    oldFolder.renameTo(newFolder);
    Log.d("renamesuccess", isSuccesfullyRenamed+"");
}
```